# Xterm -fa works, but not xterm*faceName

Tags: xterm

I have the font (listed by `fc-list`):

```
/usr/share/fonts/misc/Inconsolata-dz for Powerline.otf: Inconsolata\-dz for Powerline:style=dz
```

that I am trying to get to display with xterm.

As it stands, running

```
xterm -fa "Inconsolata\-dz for Powerline"
```

works just fine, but putting

```
xterm*faceName: Inconsolata\-dz for Powerline
```

in my `.Xdefaults` results in the default, broken weird font you get when an invalid font is loaded.

What is the proper way to set this font using `.Xdefaults`?

Comment: hey, did you find a solution? i'm having this exact problem right now.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem too, and neither of the answers in this question actually solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Find the font name by run:

```
fc-list :fontformat=TrueType -f "%{family}\n" |grep Powerline
```

Configure font in ~/.Xresources

```
XTerm*faceName: <font name from previous output>
XTerm*faceSize: 12
```

Apply changes on .Xresources by run:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all! The OP is saying that the `-fa` and `-fs` options work, but the `facename` and `facesize` options don't work, when given the *same parameters*

Answer (score 2):

[Here's another thread with the exact same question](https://superuser.com/questions/463414/how-to-get-truetype-fonts-to-display-in-xterm-from-a-xresources-file)

From the answer on that thread, it turns out that that you *can* use `faceName` this way, however, you must be very careful to get the capitalization correct, as the labels are case sensitive. For example, the following `.Xresources` file works correctly for me on Arch Linux, assuming one remembers to `xrdb` it.

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: monospace
XTerm*faceSize: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The "\-" looks suspicious: X resources know only a few special backslash sequences.  Perhaps just removing the backslash would work.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is not caused by the backslash. I am having the same issue with a font name that doesn't have any backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Use `xterm*font: Inconsolata\-dz for Powerline` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\`. I had the same issue with the same font, this ended up working for me:

`xterm*faceName: Inconsolata\\-dz for Powerline`